# If $\lim_{x \to \infty}[g(x)/f(x)]=0$ can $g(x)+f(x)$ be replaced by $f(x)$ anywhere in a limit at infinity?

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $F$, $f$ and $g$ are all contenious functions, and that:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left[\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \right] = 0$$
In a sense, $f(x)$ "dominates" $g(x)$ as $x$ becomes very large. My question is now whether the following statement holds:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} [F \bigl(f(x)+g(x) \bigr)] = \lim_{x \to \infty} [F \bigl(f(x)\bigr)]  $$
I'm convinced that this is true, since we can rewrite $f(x)+g(x)$ to
$$ \frac{f(x)}{f(x)}*(f(x)+g(x)) = f(x)*\left(1+\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \right)  $$
Now, taking the limit:
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} [F \left(f(x)*\left(1+\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \right) \right)] =  $$
$$ F \left(\lim_{x \to \infty}[f(x)] * \left(1+ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left[\frac{g(x)}{f(x)} \right]  \right) \right) = $$
$$ F(\lim_{x \to \infty}[f(x)]*(1+0)) = $$
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty}[F(f(x))]  $$
I'm pretty doubtfull though, since i don't know alot about limits, and i feel that this result is a bit too general / overpowered.

Comment: Are we given that $F$ is continuous?

Comment: This is indeed true if $\lim Ff$ exists, and this is not "overpowered" since it is a particular case of the result that limit of a product is the product of limits. There is an issue with your proof, you took $F$ outside the limit.

Comment: In fact what you have written is a generalization of how limits, where the variable tends to $\infty$, are solved: we take out the dominant term and the less dominant terms vanish. For example,$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^3+x^2+1}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^3(2+x^{-1}+x^{-3})}{x^3}=2$$

Comment: @BenGrossman Updated the post. Thanks for the notice